# EXC_BREAKPOINT when using onesignal

Tags: ios, onesignal

im trying to use onesignal to send push notification from one user to another. their documentation is really simple to use, so im not sure if my problem lies with something im doing wrong. below is the code that im using to send a notification from `testDevice1` to `testDevice2` where `af59f188-583b-blah-blah-player_ID` is my `testDevice2` playerID

```
- (IBAction)save:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"contents" : @{@"en": @"New Task!"},
                           @"include_player_ids": @[@"af59f188-583b-blah-blah-player_ID"]
                           };

    [oneSignal postNotification:dict];
}
```

this is the error i get https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JyRm.jpg

> EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1830f510c)

my google fu yeild nothing good when searching for that subcode

Comment: Make sure you only create one `OneSignal` instance in your code. Creating multiple can create unexpected errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Heres how i solved this issue

according to @jkasten's comment

> Make sure you only create one OneSignal instance in your code. Creating multiple can create unexpected errors.

hmm, ok. I bust out my google fu, and came across this

```
- (AppDelegate *)appDelegate {
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

because i have onesignal in my appdelegate when im launching to register, i decided to always use this instance of oneSignal

i call oneSignal with  `[[self appDelegate] oneSignal]`

Answer (score 0):

The code triggered an Exception breakpoint, which means some code failed and raised an Exception - probably in sendAsynchronousRequest, which was probably invoked from oneSignal.

The thread ends at CFRelease, so it could be that a Core Foundation object was sent for release.

Given your ingress into the crash, it may have something to do with the nested structure of that Dict not being to Onesignal spec, and Onesignal not handling that case appropriately. So double-check their documentation for that notification dict spec.

Also, you may want to replace all of those bare literals with variables to help make this more legible - literals are great, but its much easier if you limit their use to kv pairs with no nesting.

HTH

Comment: literally copy pasted the code from onesignal `https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-api#section-postnotification` same error with or without using `NSDictionary *dict;` the literals will be variables eventually, but this is the most simplest form in which i can reproduce the problem so i kept it as simple as possible. once i figure out the cause, i can build from there.